# Opencv contour rectangle on musical notations

Tags: android, opencv, contour

I am trying to draw the contour of every element in a picture with separated musical notations.

[image: musical notations]

This is the code that I am running in android/java:

```
public static Bitmap findNotationContours(Bitmap inputImage) {
Mat inputImageMat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(inputImage, inputImageMat);

Imgproc.cvtColor(inputImageMat, inputImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(inputImageMat, inputImageMat, new Size(5, 5), 0);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(inputImageMat, inputImageMat, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2);

List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(inputImageMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

int contourColor = android.R.color.holo_red_dark;
Scalar contourScalar = new Scalar(Color.red(contourColor), Color.green(contourColor), Color.blue(contourColor));

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
  Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
  Imgproc.rectangle(inputImageMat,
          new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
          new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
          contourScalar, 3);
}


Utils.matToBitmap(inputImageMat, inputImage);
return inputImage;
```

}

The result I am getting is:

[image: result]

If you zoom in enough you can see that the contour for the notations are there, but I need to keep the original picture with just a rectangle contour around each of them, so I can save those as a pattern.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: By the time you start drawing into `inputImageMat`, you already turned it into 1-channel (grayscale) image, yet you draw into it as if it was 3-channel image (RGB).

Comment: I have created another Mat of the initial inputImage and I drew the rectangles found from the 1-channel image on that. And it fixed the problem. So thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the crucial information from **@Dan Mašek** the problem was fixed, I will add the revised code that needs no explanation, just that we keep a Mat with the initial 3-channel image which we use to draw the contour rectangles on.

```
public static Bitmap findNotationContours(Bitmap inputImage) {
Mat inputImageMat = new Mat();
Mat resultImageMat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(inputImage, inputImageMat);
Utils.bitmapToMat(inputImage, resultImageMat);

Imgproc.cvtColor(inputImageMat, inputImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(inputImageMat, inputImageMat, new Size(5, 5), 0);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(inputImageMat, inputImageMat, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2);

List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(inputImageMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

Scalar contourScalar = new Scalar(255,0,0);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
  Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
  Imgproc.rectangle(resultImageMat,
          new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
          new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
          contourScalar, 3);
  Log.i("contour", "contour" + i + " x:" + rect.x + " y:" + rect.y);
}


Utils.matToBitmap(resultImageMat, inputImage);
return inputImage;
```

}

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCqmG.png)